# To import data into mysql

Tags: java, mysql

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Formatter;

    public class JtoCModified {
        private static final String COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";
        private static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        private static final String             DB_CONNECTION="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test2";
        private static final String DB_USER = "root";
        private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "root";

    private static int RECORD_COUNT =24;
    static final String DATEFORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    static final String TIME_FORMAT = "HH:mm:ss";
    private static final int ADD_MINUTES = 2;
    static final String FromDate = "2016-01-01 00:00:00";


    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
            StringBuffer record = new StringBuffer();
            DateFormat d_f = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
            DateFormat tf = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(d_f.parse(FromDate));
            record.append("\t");

            for (int i = 1; i <= RECORD_COUNT; i++) {
                if (i % 100000 == 0) {
                    records = new ArrayList<String>(RECORD_COUNT);
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < 2730; j++) {
                    int OPV = 230 + j % 15; // 230 - 244 by 1
                    String String = Integer.toString(OPV);
                    String str = Integer.toString(OPV);
                    record.append("OPV");

                    double IKW = 1.3 + j % 17 * 0.1; // 1.3 - 2.9 by 0.1 
                    String aString = Double.toString(IKW);
                    String IKW2 = String.valueOf(IKW);
                    record.append("IKW"); 


                    double OKW = 0.01 + j % 49 * 0.01; // 0.01 - 0.49 by 0.01
                    String bString = Double.toString(IKW);
                    String OKW2 = String.valueOf(OKW);
                    record.append("OKW"); 

                    double OPI = 0.05 + j % 105 * 0.01; // 0.05 - 1.09 by 0.01
                    String cString = Double.toString(OPI);
                    String OPI2 = String.valueOf(OPI);
                    record.append("OPI"); 


                    double IPI = 0.00 + j % 8 * 0.01;
                    String dString = Double.toString(IPI);
                    String IPI2 = String.valueOf(IPI);
                    record.append("IPI"); 

                    int NA1 = 000;
                    String eString = Integer.toString(NA1);
                    String NA12 = Integer.toString(NA1);
                    record.append("NA1");


                    int BVV = 104 + j % 13;
                    String fString = Integer.toString(BVV);
                    String BVV2 = Integer.toString(BVV);
                    record.append("BVV");

                    double BVI = 1.3 + j % 15 * 0.8;
                    String gString = Double.toString(BVI);
                    String BVI2 = String.valueOf(BVI);
                    record.append("BVI"); 


                    int NA2 = 000;
                    String hString = Integer.toString(NA2);
                    String NA22 = Integer.toString(NA2);
                    record.append("NA2");

                    int NA3 = 000;
                    String iString = Integer.toString(NA3);
                    String NA32 = Integer.toString(NA3);
                    record.append("NA3");

                    int IPV = 241 + j % 1;
                    String jString = Integer.toString(IPV);
                    String IPV2 = Integer.toString(IPV);
                    record.append("IPV");

                    int _IF = 50;
                    String kString = Integer.toString(_IF);
                    String _IF2 = Integer.toString(_IF);
                    record.append("_IF");

                    int _OF = 50;
                    String lString = Integer.toString(_OF);
                    String _OF2 = Integer.toString(_OF);
                    record.append("_OF");

                    int NA4 = 000;
                    String mString = Integer.toString(NA4);
                    String NA42 = Integer.toString(NA4);
                    record.append("NA4");

                    int SERIAL = 12345;
                    String oString = Integer.toString(SERIAL);
                    String SERIAL2 = Integer.toString(SERIAL);
                    record.append("SERIAL");

                    int NA5 = 000;
                    String nString = Integer.toString(NA4);
                    String NA52 = Integer.toString(NA5);
                    record.append("NA5");

                    int NA6 = 000;
                    String qString = Integer.toString(NA6);
                    String NA62 = Integer.toString(NA6);
                    record.append("NA6");

                    int STATUS = 000 + j % 001;
                    String rString = Integer.toString(STATUS);
                    String STATUS2 = Integer.toString(STATUS);
                    record.append("STATUS");

                    int PVV=000;
                    String sString = Integer.toString(PVV);
                    String PVV2 = Integer.toString(NA2);
                    record.append("PVV");

                    double PVI=00.0;
                    String tString = Double.toString(PVI);
                    String PVI2 = String.valueOf(OPI);
                    record.append("PVI"); 


                    double PKW=00.0;
                    String uString = Double.toString(PKW);
                    String PKW2 = String.valueOf(PKW);
                    record.append("PKW"); 


                    double PKWH=00.0;
                    String vString = Double.toString(PKWH);
                    String PKWH2 = String.valueOf(PKWH);
                    record.append("PKWH"); 

                    record.append((d_f.format(cal.getTime()))+",      "+tf.format(cal.getTime()));
                    int Device_id=101;
                    addToBuffer(record, Device_id);
                    record.append("\n");
                    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, ADD_MINUTES);
                    records.add(record.toString());
                    record.delete(0, record.length());
                    addToBuffer(record,OPV);
                    addToBuffer(record,IKW);
                    addToBuffer(record,OKW);
                    addToBuffer(record,OPI);
                    addToBuffer(record,IPI);
                    addToBuffer(record,NA1);
                    addToBuffer(record,BVV);
                    addToBuffer(record,BVI);
                    addToBuffer(record,NA2);
                    addToBuffer(record,NA3);
                    addToBuffer(record,IPV);
                    addToBuffer(record,_IF);
                    addToBuffer(record,_OF);
                    addToBuffer(record,NA4);
                    addToBuffer(record,SERIAL);
                    addToBuffer(record,NA5);
                    addToBuffer(record,NA6);
                    addToBuffer(record,NA6);
                    addToBuffer(record,PVV);
                    addToBuffer(record,PVI);
                    addToBuffer(record,PKW);
                    addToBuffer(record,PKWH);

                    record.delete(0, record.length());
                    record.append(OKW); 
                    record.append(OPI);
                    record.append(IPI); 
                    record.append(NA1); 
                    record.append(BVV); 
                    record.append(BVI); 
                    record.append(NA2); 
                    record.append(NA3); 
                    record.append(IPV); 
                    record.append(_IF); 
                    record.append(_OF); 
                    record.append(NA4); 
                    record.append(SERIAL);
                    record.append(NA5); 
                    record.append(NA6); 
                    record.append(STATUS);
                    record.append(PVV);
                    record.append(PVI);
                    record.append(PKW);
                    record.append(PKWH);
                    record.append(STATUS); 
                    record.append((d_f.format(cal.getTime()))+", "+tf.format(cal.getTime()));
                    record.append("\t\t");
                    record.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
              //      int Device_id=101;
                    addToBuffer(record, Device_id);
                    record.append("\n");
                    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, ADD_MINUTES);
                    records.add(record.toString());              

                    String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"

                    + "(OPV, IKW, OKW ,OPI, IPI,NA1, BVV, BVI,NA2, NA3,IPV, _IF, _OF,NA4 , SERIAL ,NA5, NA6, STATUS ,PVI ,PKW , PKWH) "

                    + "VALUES" + "("+ OPV + IKW +  OKW + OPI + IPI + NA1 + BVV + BVI + NA2 + NA3 + IPV + _IF + _OF + NA4 + SERIAL + NA5 + NA6 + STATUS+ PVI + PKW + PKWH +")";  

          //  record.append("\t\t");
            record.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);        

            try {

                insertRecordIntoDbUserTable();

                Connection dbConnection = null;
                Statement statement = null;
                dbConnection = getDBConnection();
                statement = dbConnection.createStatement();

                System.out.println(insertTableSQL);

                // execute insert SQL stetement
                statement.executeUpdate(insertTableSQL);
                System.out.println(insertTableSQL);

                System.out.println("Record is inserted into DbUser table!");

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                System.out.println(e.getMessage());

            } finally {

            }

        }       

    }

  }
private static void addToBuffer(StringBuffer buffer, Object data) {
            buffer.append(data);
            buffer.append(", ");
        }

        private static void insertRecordIntoDbUserTable() 
        {

        }

        private static Connection getDBConnection() {

            Connection dbConnection = null;

            try {

                Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

                System.out.println(e.getMessage());

            }

            try {

                dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                                   DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
                return dbConnection;

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                System.out.println(e.getMessage());

            }

            return dbConnection;

        }
}
```

I want to export data from java to mysql db but i am not getting any data, initially i want to print the data in console after that i want to add into a database table .I have done jdbc connectivity.But still its not fetching any data please suggest me something.I am getting data in console but not in format what should i do to make the console data in format and to export data into db.

Comment: Please help if anybody knows the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the SQL statement you create here:

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"

+ "(OPV, IKW, OKW ,OPI, IPI,NA1, BVV, BVI,NA2, NA3,IPV, _IF, _OF,NA4 , SERIAL ,NA5, NA6, STATUS ,PVI ,PKW , PKWH) "

+ "VALUES" + "("+ OPV + IKW +  OKW + OPI + IPI + NA1 + BVV + BVI + NA2 + NA3 + IPV + _IF + _OF + NA4 + SERIAL + NA5 + NA6 + STATUS+ PVI + PKW + PKWH +")";
```

Print out the `insertTableSQL` string to see what it actually contains.

Also, I think there should be an error message printed by this:

```
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
```

Show it to us.

---

**UPDATE**

```
INSERT INTO DBUSER(OPV, IKW, OKW ,OPI, IPI,NA1, BVV, BVI,NA2, 
   NA3,IPV, _IF, _OF,NA4 , SERIAL ,NA5, NA6, STATUS ,PVI ,PKW , PKWH)
   VALUES(2341.70000000000000020.050.090.0401084.50024150500123450000.00.00.0)
```

As I suspected, the problem is that your string concatenation has resulted in an SQL statement with one long meaningless "value".  It is invalid SQL.

The solutions:

1. Put commas between the values in your concatenation.
2. Use a `PreparedStatement` instead of a `Statement` with `?` placeholders, and then use `setXxxx` to set the query arguments.

Comment: INSERT INTO DBUSER(OPV, IKW, OKW ,OPI, IPI,NA1, BVV, BVI,NA2, NA3,IPV, _IF, _OF,NA4 , SERIAL ,NA5, NA6, STATUS ,PVI ,PKW , PKWH) VALUES(2341.70000000000000020.050.090.0401084.50024150500123450000.00.00.0)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.050.090.0401084.50024150500123450000.00.00.0)' at line 1
here is what i am getting in output with an error @Stephen C